# Do Wondrous Items require the Use Magic Device skill?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Do characters need to do a check to use items like, for example, the [Rope of Knots](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/rope-of-knots), or can anyone use them?

Answer (score 5):

## Most of the time anyone can use wondrous items

The Magic Items section on [Wondrous Items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items) under the heading Activation says

> Wondrous items are usually use-activated or activated by a command word, but details vary from item to item.
>
> **Command Word:** If the activation is on command or if no activation method is suggested either in the magic item description or by the nature of the item, assume that a command word is needed to activate it. Command word activation means that a character speaks the word and the item activates. No other special knowledge is needed.
>
> A command word can be a real word, but [when this is the case, the holder of the item runs the risk of activating the item accidentally by speaking the word in normal conversation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36287/8610). More often, the command word is some nonsensical word, or a word or phrase from an ancient language. Activating a command word magic item is a standard action and does not provoke attacks of opportunity.
>
> Sometimes the command word to activate an item is written right on the item. Occasionally, it might be hidden within a pattern or design engraved, carved, or built into the item, or the item might bear a clue to the command word.
>
> The Knowledge (arcana) and Knowledge (history) skills can be useful in identifying command words or deciphering clues regarding them. In such cases, a successful DC 30 check is needed to come up with the word itself. If that check is failed, succeeding on a second check (DC 25) might provide a clue. The spells *detect magic*, *identify*, and *analyze dweomer* all reveal command words if the properties of the item are successfully identified.

Also, hidden in the section on Intelligent Wondrous Items, the game says that even a non-intelligent wondrous item has a 30% chance that

> Something (a design, inscription, or the like) provides a clue to [an item's] function (or if the item is command word-activated, that it has the command word or words written on it).

Thus if the item's possessor knows the command word, the possessor can take a standard action to employ the wondrous item.

Further, a creature *can* employ the skill [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device) (DC 25) to activate blindly a command-word-activated magic item for which he does't know the command word.

It's possible, though, that the wondrous item might be easier to use than that because some are

> **Use-Activated:** This type of item merely has to be used in order to activate it. A character has to drink a potion, swing a sword, interpose a shield to deflect a blow, look through a lens, sprinkle dust, wear a ring, or don a hat. Use activation is generally straightforward and self-explanatory.
>
> Many use-activated items are objects that a character wears. Continually functioning items are practically always items that one wears. A few must simply be in the character's possession (meaning on her person). However, some items made for wearing must still be activated. Although this activation sometimes requires a command word (see above), usually it means mentally willing the activation. The description of an item states whether a command word is needed in such a case.

However, this **is** *Pathfinder*, so exceptions *will* exist as to which creatures can use certain items, but those exceptions will *either* be listed in the item's description *or* specify a different activation method. The [*rope of knots*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/rope-of-knots) is **not** an exception, functioning as it does "upon command," a standard action.

Comment: One is still required to _know_ the command word. UMD check is applicable if one doesn't.

Comment: The items have a clearly-defined use case: CW-activated, command word not known by the user. This use case doesn't seem to be a uniquely rare occurence, so yes, it's worth mentioning.

Comment: How often do the adventurers find the command-word activated magical items with a user manual nearby?