# Command word activation questions

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

I was working on a Pathfinder Character build for the whole 20 levels. As a monk you really have no ability with casting spells (with minor exceptions using the new Unchained rules and the one archtype which grants a couple of spells) or with Use Magic Device.
I had considered taking a level of Rogue (this was before unchained) or another magic class to gain access to some of the low level spells which would be very helpful. By gaining access to I mean either the ability to cast them directly or without needing to make a UMD check because its now on my spell list (provided no other restrictions). So I was planning a bunch of low level magic items that would stack really well for the character.
While I was going over the magic item creation rules I came across

> "A command word can be a real word, but when this is the case, the holder of the item runs the risk of activating the item accidentally by speaking the word in normal conversation." 
>   http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation

So, while I have never encountered this having happened in a game I came up with 3 important questions.

1. Can you have multiple items made to the same keyword and thus trigger at the same time? This question has mostly been answered, look near the bottom of the post to find the link.
2. Could you make an item with multiple trigger words? How would this be priced?
3. Could you force other people's items to activate and intentionally fail the UMD check to cause a bad result?

I had felt that since activating an item is a standard action usually, that the accidental activation should not be possible as it almost implies the desire or force of will to activate it.

It was pointed out that [Is possible to Chain-Activate Pearls of Power?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36281/23058) has a very similar question when used with Pearls of Power (which is why I didnt realize they were similar questions at first, so thank you for pointing that out). While this does sort of answer question 1, it doesnt answer the other 2.

Comment: [Partially answered here.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36281/is-possible-to-chain-activate-pearls-of-power) (*Pathfinder* and *D&D 3.5* **really** aren't different in this regard.) Consider cutting your question to the unanswered ones.

Comment: This needs to be three different questions, I think. They're not inter-related or inter-dependent and don't require going over the same concepts. They just all happen to be command word questions. One's a question about using magic items, another's a question about crafting them, the last is a question about activation in another way that doesn't cover the same ground as the others.