# Can magical items have more than one command word?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Can a magical item, have multiple command words to trigger activation? How does this affect the making of the item?

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62596/23058 I hope yours gets answered

Comment: No offence ment, but I have to agree with the reason for closing. You asked three separate questions all that could be answered rather indepth. This only was asking about one of the three points you brought up! (however I am curious about the others, and if they are ever asked separately I would love to know the answers!)

Comment: None taken, I just never got around to fixing the question after the issue was pointed out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two interpretations of your question.  So, I will answer them both.

Do you mean:

**Q:  Can an item with multiple functions have different command words for each function?**

A:  Yes.  In fact it is assumed since otherwise, you would not know what would trigger when you said the command word.  Though, you may argue that this was what created the wand of wonder (rod in Pathfinder).

**Q: Can a single function on a magic item have more than one command word?**

There is no rules as written method of doing this.  Personally, i don't see the point but you you may have spotted something that I haven't thought of.

Conceptually, I don't see why not but anything you do for this would be a house rule.  As far as the cost goes, it probably shouldn't be as expensive as adding in another copy of the same function just to get another command word but it shouldn't be free.  Custom is always more expensive.

Remember that [Identify](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/identify/) will give all command words of the item.

> This spell functions as detect magic, except that it gives you a +10
>   enhancement bonus on Spellcraft checks made to identify the properties
>   and command words of magic items in your possession. This spell does
>   not allow you to identify artifacts.

Comment: I was looking specifically at the gravespawn gland necrograft! http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/necrograft/
If the command word is spoken within 60 ft, it goes boom. Doesnt matter by who it seems. Figured if I wanted someone dead but didnt want it to happen infront of me, i could set up some super common command words and let it happen when they, or others talk. Say, If he said head, help, gravespawn, or any common command word or info i wouldnt want him to spill.

Comment: @Erudaki Make it trigger on something super common and place it in their desk. Something everybody uses all the time. Let's see, where'd I put it and welcome might be favorites, but also hello, welcome or simply: I would do the trick.

Comment: Keen observers will note, It must be placed within their head, during an hour long surgical procedure.... (that they were likely unconscious for) hence why I used head and help XD

Comment: For an example of a magic item which explicitly has different command words for different functions, see the *decanter of endless water*.

Comment: The rules seem to contradict themselves. First, it says that you can accidentally activate the magic item if the command word is too common. Then it says it requires a standard action. If it could be accidentally activated, I would simply use a free action and use the word during my speech. I would go with "*you cannot accidentally activate a command word item*" as a ruling.

Comment: I believe the standard action is for directing the effect. IE Pointing a wand at a target. Otherwise the wand would go off with no target, or blast a fireball at your feet. Hence why they state by default the words are jibberish.

Comment: @GMJoe Yes, different command words for different functions make sense, my question however is asking about having different words for the same function.

Comment: @Erudaki The question doesn't actually specify. If that is an important part of the question, it should be included in the question. Either way, this answer does mention both types of item, and would be improved by including examples.

Comment: You do have a point. That is something I should have made more clear. I honestly didnt even think of having multiple enchantments with different effects on one item tbh.

Comment: @Erudaki, just make the command word a common greeting.  Someone's bound to say it some time.  Just make sure the target is far away before they wake up from the implant procedure.